# Create a not found ServerResponse if a Mono is empty

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, kotlin-coroutines

I am using  Spring Boot 2.2.6, Kotlin and coroutines to implement a simple reactive rest API. I am trying to use the [functional style](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines#mono-flux-flow).

How can I change the following code to return the 404 HTTP response if the repository returns an empty `Mono<Task>` (`Task` is a simple class of mine domain model)?

```
suspend fun findOne(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
    val id = request.pathVariable("id")
    val task = repository.findById(id)
    return ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .json()
            .bodyAndAwait(task.asFlow())
}
```

Pay attention that I am using coroutines. I need an instance of `Flow`. Examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903813/webflux-functional-how-to-detect-an-empty-flux-and-return-404) do not apply.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real question is how to transform a Mono into a suspended result.

Please take a look [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive/kotlinx.coroutines.reactive/org.reactivestreams.-publisher/await-first-or-null.html).

Actually, this approach is being used in the example that you are looking.
Check [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/baeldung/nonblockingcoroutines/repository/ProductRepositoryCoroutines.kt)

**Update (add the code)**

```
suspend fun findOne(req: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val id  = req.pathVariable("id").toInt()
        return taskRepo.findById(id)
                .flatMap { task->ServerResponse.ok().json().body<Task>(task) }
                .switchIfEmpty { ServerResponse.notFound().build() }
                .awaitSingle()

    }
```

**Update 2**
Created a small demo project [here](https://github.com/routis/spring-coroutines/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/routis/sample/springcoroutines/task.kt).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you give me a concrete example, starting from my code snippet?

Comment: var task : Task? = repository.findById(id).awaitFirstOrNull()

Then you check if task is null and return the response that you want

Comment: Also, you can change the controller's function to return just the Task? instead of ServerResponse.